# Customize CKEditor Link dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to add an additional drop down options to the Link `infoTab` of the Link Dialog in CKEditor. How do I do that?

[image: Inside the red square]

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are talking about the `protocol` dropdown in `infoTab`. If that is the case then please use [dialogDefinition event](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-event-dialogDefinition) to get to right dialog and field inside it.

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {});
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if ( dialogName == 'link' ){
        var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );
        var protocolDropdown = infoTab.get( 'protocol' );
        protocolDropdown.items.push( ['xyz', 'XYZ'] );
    }
});
```